# Mac OS X Leopard showing different version of Rails after install

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

so I'm installing rails with

```
gem install rails
```

and I didn't have any version of rails prior to the one I'm installing (3.0.9).

By the time the installation finishes I get the documentation error

```
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.9...
file 'lib' not found
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.0.9...
```

Even though it says that rails 3.0.9 was installed successfully.

If I run

```
gem list rails
```

it shows me version 3.0.9, but when I run

```
rails -v
```

it shows me version 2.3.5 ( I don't know here that came from ).

See: http://cl.ly/353h1o1b3y3T260L3F3p

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really care, just remove rails 2.3.5 with `gem uninstall rails` and chose the appropriate one when it asks you which.

Comment: Hi Zach, thanks for that, but it didn't work.

I've used `gem uninstall rails` but all it did was uninstall rails 3.0.9. Looks like rails 2.3.5 is still there somewhere. Take a look: http://cl.ly/2V072u1z15383e0i2P1g

Comment: You may have 2 environments going on. In your position I'd remove all instances of Ruby I could find and then start from fresh with rvm. Good luck!